# Save Live Agent PreChat Field to Beginning of Chat Log

Tags: liveagent, livechattranscript

I find that there's a way to save prechat data to a custom field on the Live Chat Transcript object. For example, if I want to save a prechat Question to the Live Chat Transcript object, I would do the following in the prechat form.

```
<input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:Question' placeholder="What's your question?" id='subject'/>
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:Question" value="Question__c" />
```

However, I would like to save this field to the first line in the Body of the chat transcript so that the first thing the agent sees in the chat window from the customer is the question they posed on the prechat form. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Custom Chat Window then you can do this following way.

Pass the Question from Pre-Chat window to Chat window with the help of a Cookie. Refer to this [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175643&type=1) for more details.

Once the Chat window loads, retrieve the Question from Cookie populate the Chat Input Field and Send the Chat by clicking the Send button with the help of JavaScript. So this will be the First message receive by Agent.

You have to write the JavaScript code in the ChatEstablished event. As per Salesforce this event *Indicates that an agent has accepted a chat request and is engaged in a chat with a visitor*.

The JavaScript code that do the magic.

```
liveagent.addEventListener(liveagent.chasitor.Events.CHAT_ESTABLISHED,myCallBack);
function myCallBack() { 
  document.getElementById("liveAgentChatInput").value = ReadCookie("prechat_question");
  document.getElementsByClassName("liveAgentSendButton")[0].click();;
}
```

Complete Chat Window Code

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
    <style>
        body { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0 }
        #waitingMessage { height: 100%; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; display: none; }
        #liveAgentClientChat.liveAgentStateWaiting #waitingMessage { display: table; }
        #liveAgentSaveButton, #liveAgentEndButton { z-index: 2; }
        .liveAgentChatInput {
            height: 25px;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #000;
            padding: 2px 0 2px 4px;
            background: #fff;
            display: block;
            width: 99%;
        }
        .liveAgentSendButton {
            display: block;
            width: 60px;
            height: 31px;
            padding: 0 0 3px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: -67px;
        }
        #liveAgentChatLog {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            top: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            overflow-y: auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        liveagent.addEventListener(liveagent.chasitor.Events.CHAT_ESTABLISHED,myCallBack);
        function myCallBack() { 
          document.getElementById("liveAgentChatInput").value = ReadCookie("prechat_question");
          document.getElementsByClassName("liveAgentSendButton")[0].click();;
        }
        function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
            var theCookie = " " + document.cookie;
            var ind = theCookie.indexOf(" " + cookieName + "=");
            if (ind == -1) ind = theCookie.indexOf(";" + cookieName + "=");
            if (ind == -1 || cookieName == "") return "";
            var ind1 = theCookie.indexOf(";", ind + 1);
            if (ind1 == -1) ind1 = theCookie.length;
            return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind + cookieName.length + 2, ind1));
        }    
    </script>    
    <div style="top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute;">
        <liveAgent:clientchat >
            <liveAgent:clientChatSaveButton label="Save Chat" />
            <liveAgent:clientChatEndButton label="End Chat" />
            <div style="top: 25px; left: 5px; right: 5px; bottom: 5px; position: absolute; z-index:0;">
                <liveAgent:clientChatAlertMessage />
                <liveAgent:clientChatStatusMessage />
                <table id="waitingMessage" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Please wait while you are connected to an available agent.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 41px; left: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; word-wrap: break-word; z-index: 0;">
                    <liveAgent:clientChatLog />
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; height: auto; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin-right:67px;">
                    <liveagent:clientChatInput /><liveAgent:clientChatSendButton label="Send"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </liveAgent:clientchat>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

This Chat Window is taken from [Live Agent Developer's Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/186/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/live_agent_dev_guide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the time, Saroj. This seems like a possible solution, though it's beyond our current scope to develop a custom chat window. If our project grows, we'll try this option.

Comment: @Jonathan building a basic custom chat window is very simple. You can just use the same code as given above provided in Live Agent Guide.

Comment: Just so you know, I ended up going the custom chat window route anyway. Styling was a pain, but I appreciate the extra flexibility. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree you have to play with the styling but it is worth of effort. If you stuck anywhere please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Winter ’18 Release Notes > Service > Snap-ins for Web >

Pre-Chat Form Records Automatically Attach to the Chat Transcript
When records are created from the pre-chat form in your snap-in, they’re automatically attached to the chat transcript. Previously, agents had to manually attach created records to the chat transcript. This change applies to both Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Alan. Obviously, this feature didn't exist at the time this question was asked. Thank you for updating the answer to this old question.